# Membership is renewed instead of created when filling out form in link

Tags: civimember, renewals

In our installation of CiviCRM we have one-time memberships and recurring memberships. When participants have a one-time membership that will expire soon, they should receive an email with a personalized link where they should be able to create a recurring membership.
The link is: `crm.ourinstallation.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2&cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}`
where id=2 refers to the Contribution page number 2.
This email is sent one week before the one-time Membership expires, i.e. the one-time Membership will mostly have the status "ongoing" when the form is filled out, but it could also happen that participants will only fill out the form after their membership has expired.

When I fill out this form as a test user, the system does not create a new recurring Membership (while keeping the expired one-time Membership). This would be ok in general, but the values of End Date as well as other fields are not deleted/changed. Which means that the recurring Membership automatically expires at the end date of the previous one-time Membership, which is wrong.

Configuring the Contribution page with ID 2, there are two areas "Registration" and "Renewal". I can set a title and a text for both of them. It seems that when the current membership is already expired, the "Renewal" area will show to the user in the form, while the "Registration" area will show when the current membership has the status Ongoing. **However, no matter if I fill out "Renewal" or "Registration", in both cases no new membership is created (but the status of the old one changed).**

Now, I figured out that when I change the form link to `crm.ourinstallation.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2&cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}?mid=1`, I can deliberately produce an invalid membership renewal. In this case, I have a warning popping up: `The membership you are trying to renew seems to be invalid. Contact the admin of your website if you need help. If you continue, a new membership will be created.` (translated by me) It was my idea for a workaround to simply use this page and hide the warning per CSS, so participants would always just create new memberships.

**However, also if I continue, no new membership will be created (but the status of the old one changed), even though the warning explicitly says so.**

Is this expected behavior? How can I create a personalized link to create an additional membership of type recurring?

**Edit** @petednz: The system has one membership type ("Test Membership") for one-off, and three membership types (monthly, quarterly, yearly) for recurring.

**Edit2** @PradeepNayak: The membership is indeed renewed when the payment is completed, but the end date is wrong then. For example, I create a one-off membership for 2 months on April 06. It ends on June 06. Then, on June 20, I want to create a recurring membership (monthly payments) via the personalized online form. I pay the first payment and the membership renews until July 06. This is wrong (should be July 20).

Creating a second organisation is not really an option for the long-term, as many more membership types should be implemented in the future. Sth like guitar course, drums course... We would need a new organisation with a new membership type for every single new course. Which seems like a huge overload.

Comment: not clear to me if you have a different Membership Type or you are using the same Type for both one-off and recurring.

Comment: I think the 'overload' of having to create a bunch of new Contacts (one per new membership) may be a lot less than a customisation to achieve what you want, if as Pradeep suggests, having each Membership operate independently requires them each being associated to a different Org.

Answer (score 3):

If the membership type belong to same organization then Civi will renew the membership i.e push the end date and status when the payment is completed.

If you want multiple membership I would suggest to create second org and have the other membership set to second org.